# Android : Constructing bitmap from RECT

Tags: android

Can we construct a bitmap from a rect.

I draw a bitmap in a rect and want strokes drawn on the bitmap image become part of the image.

I am wondering if I can construct a bitmap from a Rect so the new bitmap has the old image and the strokes as a single image.

Thank You

Comment: afaik, you can create a canvas with a bitmap and draw the rect/stroke on the same canvas, and now your bitmap will have the drawing on it. give it a try

Answer (score 3):

You can always take a canvas to help you create an already decoded bitmap the way you want:

```
Bitmap originalBmp = null;//Here goes original Bitmap...
ImageView img = null;//Any imageview holder you are using...
Bitmap modifiedBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);//Configure with your proper size and color
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(modifiedBmp);

//At this point the modified bitmap has the original one, starting from here, you can add any overlay you want...
canvas.drawBitmap(originalBmp, 0, 0, new Paint());

//And do all the other modifications you want here...
canvas.drawLines(new float[]{}, null);
canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, null);

//At this point the modified bitmap will have anything you added
img.setImageBitmap(modifiedBmp);

// IF YOU ARE OVERRIDING ONDRAW METHOD
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

    //Here DO your DRAW BITMAP NOTE: paint must be already created...
    canvas.drawBitmap(bt, 0, 0, paint);

    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    canvas.drawRect(30, 30, 80, 80, paint);

    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Regards!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :) 
But I am already drawing a bitmap in the canvas in the draw method 
canvas.drawBitmap(bt,null,cardPicRect,p);
where bt is my bitmap,  cardPicRect is the Rect in which i draw the bitmap and p is the paint object.
I am not sure if i can construct a new canvas with the bitmap.   Can i construct a canvas in a canvas.

Comment: If you are overriding onDraw(Canvas canvas), you can add another call to make the rect frame with lines, after the method "canvas.drawBitmap(bt,null,cardPicRect,p);" you already have

Comment: Hi martin thanks for the quick response.
But i did not understand what you meant by you can add another call to make the rect frame with lines 
Can you please explain me 
Thank You

Comment: look at my edit for onDraw method, that is something like what you should be doing

Comment: the lines are drawn by the user as strokes using the stylus.  So if i not wrong the basic idea is to construct a canvas with a bitmap object.  Now whatever we draw on canvas is now part of the bitmap.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: In the first example i gave you thats correct, any modification to the canvas will affect "modifiedBmp", because the canvas was created using that bmp so, any line or whatever you draw using that canvas will modify the bitmap itself, for the "onDraw" implementation thats not necessarily true, because your bitmap will remain intact, but the View overriding the method, will see the bitmap and whatever else you draw will overlay it, like in the example the rectangle is not part of the bitmap is actually overlaying it...

Comment: In example two the rectangle is overlayed on the bitmap but it is not part of the bitmap correct.  My requirement is to draw a bitmap in a rect and when the user draws the stroke with a stylus on the bitmap the stroke should become part of the bitmap.  The rect can be dragged (moved) so  the image moves and now the stroke should be dragged (moved) too and maintain its original position in the image.   
So essentially the stroke should become part of the bitmap image.

Comment: In that case, the first example i gave you is the proper one, but now here comes a potential issue, you will need to start handling "recycling" bitmaps on your end to avoid OutOfMemoryErrors, have you considered having an ImageView within a LinearLayout, set a background for the linearlayout and a margin for the ImageView, so you have the "Effect of a stroke" which is actually the background of the LinearLayout and that way the OS will handle all the Bitmap recycling for you...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can , Using canvas you can draw something on your old bimtap .

```
   Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
                bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

                final int color = 0xff424242;
                final Paint paint = new Paint();

                final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

                paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
                paint.setColor(color);
                  // do some canvas drawing
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :) 

But I am already drawing a bitmap in the canvas in the draw method 
canvas.drawBitmap(bt,null,cardPicRect,p);

where bt is my bitmap,  cardPicRect is the Rect in which i draw the bitmap and p is the paint object.

I am not sure if i can construct a new canvas with the bitmap.   Can i construct a canvas in a canvas.